# Max-height based on height of other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to be able to set the max-height of one element based on the (variable) height of another one — though I'm very much a JS beginner, I'm just about positive there's a way to do so with it. This is *not* the parent element I want to base the max-height on. Obviously, I want this solution to work regardless of whatever the height of the element might be at any given time on any given page.

Just to be clear, I want to find the height of, let's say, an element with the class "ElementOne", and then set the max-height of "ElementTwo" to, say, height-of-ElementOne plus 113px.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this snippet [by Paul Irish](http://www.broken-links.com/2009/01/20/very-quick-equal-height-columns-in-jquery/#comment-23624) to do just that:

```
$.fn.setAllToMaxHeight = function(){
  return this.height( Math.max.apply(this, $.map( this , function(e){ return $(e).height() }) ) );
}

// usage: $(‘div.unevenheights’).setAllToMaxHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you mean:

```
var h = document.getElementById("ElementOne").style.height;

document.getElementById("ElementTwo").style.maxHeight = h + 113 + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses jquery to assign an event listener to the resize event of the window and ELementOne (Note: I don't think that most html trigger there own resize event). Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/UPqsV/

I add color to the divs so you can see them.

html:

```
<div class="ElementOne"></div>
<div class="ElementTwo"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function setHeight(){
    var elementOne = $(".ElementOne").height();
    $(".ElementTwo").height( elementOne +113);
}

$(window,".ElementOne").resize(setHeight);
setHeight();
```